# Spring Boot: Remove JmsHealthIndicator from actuator/health

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-boot-actuator

I need to remove `JmsHealthIndicator` so that `actuator/health` returns status OK, even if the JMS connection doesn't work.

Since `JmsHealthIndicator` is not annotated with `@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator` I cannot simply turn it off with `management.endpoint.health.jms.enabled=false`.

Is there another option?

Comment: Yes you can as the configuration class is annotated.

Comment: @M.Deinum what configuration class?

Comment: The one that configures the health checks for JMS. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/jms/JmsHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.java